# Getting help from the `C-h k`-command for named extensions

Tags: emacs, key-bindings

Is there an emacs command to get help with named-extensions?

Using `C-h k` generally gives help on the command that follows, but if the command that I'm trying to get help with begins with `M-x`, emacs gives me help with `M-x`, rather than waiting to hear the named-extension that I want help with.

I've attempted to read relevant sections of the included manual, but I've either not found the right sections, or misunderstood what I've read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is certainly:

- <kbd>C-h f</kbd> (*describe-function*: documentation of a `M-x …` command or of a noninteractive function)

Also, instead of doing <kbd>C-h c</kbd>, <kbd>C-h f</kbd> in a row, you can just as well use:

- <kbd>C-h k</kbd> (*describe-key*: documentation of a keybinding)

Note that a subset of the functions / keys are documented in more depth in emacs' `info` manual, so you may also try typing:

- <kbd>C-h F</kbd> (*Info-goto-emacs-command-node*)
- <kbd>C-h K</kbd> (*Info-goto-emacs-key-command-node*)

before the function or keybinding you are interested in.

#### Side notes

You might also be interested in installing some modes to increase the discoverability of features, namely:

- [`which-key`](https://github.com/justbur/emacs-which-key),
- [`discover-my-major`](https://framagit.org/steckerhalter/discover-my-major),
- [`helpful`](https://github.com/Wilfred/helpful).

If you're a [`use-package`](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package) user, installing them would amount to adding at the end of your `.emacs`:

```lisp
(use-package which-key
  :ensure t
  :config
  (which-key-mode))

(use-package discover-my-major
  :ensure t
  :config
  (global-set-key (kbd "C-h C-m") #'discover-my-major)
  (global-set-key (kbd "C-h M-m") #'discover-my-mode))

;; Recall we also have the standard keybinding "C-h m".

(use-package helpful
  :ensure t
  :config
  (global-set-key (kbd "C-h f") #'helpful-callable)
  (global-set-key (kbd "C-h v") #'helpful-variable)
  (global-set-key (kbd "C-h k") #'helpful-key)
  ;;; Look up Functions (excludes macros).
  ;; (global-set-key (kbd "C-h F") #'helpful-function)
  ;;; Look up Commands (= keybindings).
  ;; (global-set-key (kbd "C-h K") #'helpful-command)
  ;;; COMMENTED-OUT as "Info-goto-emacs[-key]-command-node" are more useful.
  (add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook #'(lambda ()
    (local-set-key (kbd "C-c C-.") #'helpful-at-point))))

;; Note we can also type "C-h" after a prefix to list its expansions.
```